# Doctrine 1.* cache invalidation

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-1.2

I'm using APC cache for expensive query which retrieve job with related files, payments, events etc. 
I would like to know if there are available solutions for cache invalidation in Doctrine 1.*.

I came up with following working solution, it does work, I just don't want to invent a wheel.

Please suggest me if there are better/other existing solutions.

Record listener tries to clear cache with given id's on `postSave` event:

```
class My_Doctrine_Record_Listener_ClearCache extends Doctrine_Record_Listener
{
    /**
     * Clear cache by table tags
     * 
     * @param Doctrine_Event $event
     * @return null 
     */
    public function postSave(Doctrine_Event $event)
    {
        $cache = new Doctrine_Cache_Apc(); 

        /* @var $model Doctrine_Record */
        $model = $event->getInvoker();
        $name  = get_class($model);

        /* @var $table Doctrine_Table */
        $table = $model->getTable($name);
        if (method_exists($table, 'getCacheTags')) {
            foreach ($table->getCacheTags() as $tag) {
                $id = preg_replace('/%([\w]+)%/e', '$model->{\\1}', $tag);
                $cache->delete($id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I have in tables:

```
class FileTable extends Doctrine_Table
{
   /* ... */
   public function getCacheTags()
   {
        return array(
            'job_view_%job_id%'
        );
   }
   /* ... */ 
}

class JobTable extends Doctrine_Table
{
    /* ... */
    public function getCacheTags()
    {        
        return array(
           'job_view_%id%'
        );
    }
    /* ... */ 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above solution has been used for 7 years in the production environment, so it's safe to say - it does work good enough.